# Sequential file processing in webmethods

Tags: webmethod

Can webmethods file port read files in specific sequence? like if i have file 001.xml, 003.xml, 002.xml in the monitoring folder can webmethods be configured/customized to read file in filename sequence like 001.xml, 002.xml, 003.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the files are read in no particular order. In order to process them in some order, you'd probably have to read them, publish an event (containing the file name among other data) or store the file somewhere, and then process the published events / stored files as you like.

Comment: Got to know that it pickups files based on last modified data time. So changed logic to read based on file time stamp.